# Qual a diferença entre fases de teste e técnicas de teste?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, testes, arquitetura-de-software, testes-de-unidade, testes-funcionais

Estou tentando estudar sobre testes de software e organizar os tópicos de maneira hierárquica, dividindo os diferentes tipos de técnicas de teste de software em escopos, como os testes unitários, funcionais, de desempenho etc. Porém, cada lugar que procuro para estudo se refere á esses termos de jeitos totalmente diferentes, como se um estivesse contido em outro e isso sinceramente está me confundindo mais do que precisava. Em certos websites, já vi referenciarem testes funcionais e testes de caixa preta como sinônimos, em outros como se um fosse parte do outro. Já em outros websites, já vi referenciarem as 4 principais fases de teste (unitário, integração, sistema e aceitação) como técnicas de teste de outros tipos de teste.

No geral, essas termos tem algum sentido na prática ou na teoria essa hierarquização não tem muita importância? Todos são considerados técnicas/tipos e se enquadram mais em similaridades do que em categorias? Elas possuem utilidade em frameworks de teste?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.